# How can I get attributes from the datalayer when enter in a page? Interaction Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, interaction-studio, evergage

I'm have some issues when I want to get some atrributes from `window.datalayer` in the sitemap.

Here is my sitemap code

```
{
      name: "CDC_articles",
      action: "CDC_articles",
      isMatch: () => {
          return /\/articles/.test(window.location.href);
      },
      catalog: {
           Article: {
               _id: () => document.location.pathname.split("/")[document.location.pathname.split("/").length - 1].split(".")[0],
               name: Evergage.resolvers.fromSelector("h1"),
               url: Evergage.resolvers.fromHref(),
               publicationDate: () => {
                      const articles = getArticlesFromDataLayer();
                            
                       if (articles && articles.lastPubDate.length > 0) {
                                return articles.lastPubDate;
                       }
                            return "";
                            
                },
                adiApp: () => {
                      const articles = getArticlesFromDataLayer();
                            
                       if (articles && articles.adiApp.length > 0) {
                            return articles.adiApp;
                       }

                        return "";
                },        
           }
     },
},
```

In this example, when I first land in the articles page, it loads the `_id`, `name` and `url` inmediatly. In order to get the `publicationDate` and the `adiApp` attributes I have to hit the Execute button.

This is the function that it suppose to get the values:

```
const getArticlesFromDataLayer = () => {
        if (window.dataLayer) {
            for (let i = 0; i < window.dataLayer.length; i++) {
                //if (window.dataLayer[i].hasOwnProperty('adiApp') && window.dataLayer[i].hasOwnProperty('adiBu') && window.dataLayer[i].hasOwnProperty('lastPubDate')) {
                if(window.dataLayer[i].adiApp || window.dataLayer[i].adiBu || window.dataLayer[i].lastPubDate){
                    return window.dataLayer[i];
                }
            }
        }
};
```

The `window.datalayer` object:

```
window.dataLayer = [
  {...}, {...}, {...},
  {
    "zipCode": null,
    "siteID": "catDotCom",
    "dealerId": null,
    "dealerCode": null,
    "dealerName": null,
    "dealerLocationName": null,
    "templateID": "t4-article-template",
    "templateBase": "deg",
    "adiBu": "bcp",
    "adiApp": "construction",
    "adiContType": "awareness",
    "adiInd": "snow and ice",
    "adiAud": "anonymous | marketing qualified prospect",
    "adiAudgoal": "awareness",
    "adiPripgkpi": "pageviews",
    "adiSecpgkpi": "time on page",
    "storeID": null,
    "storeCode": null,
    "storeName": null,
    "lastPubDate": "2021-08-27T11:35:00.000-05:00",
    "catRecId": "PSP-00058E58",
    "userId": "juliar2"
  }
]
```

So, how can I get those attributes rigth away whe the users gets to the articles page?

Thanks for you time.